# Why am I getting token errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure why I am getting a token error statement. The error is
`SyntaxError: bad token T_OP on line 7`

```
import math

def law_of_cosines(a,b,theta):

    math.sqrt(int((a**2) + (b**2) − (2*(a)*(b)*(math.cos(math.degrees(theta))))))
 
   
res1 = law_of_cosines(3.0, 4.0, 90)
print(res1)  # should output: 5.0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: SyntaxError: bad token T_OP on line 7

Comment: Please include the full traceback error in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the minus sign your `−` should be `-`

```py
import math

def law_of_cosines(a, b, theta):

    return math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 - (2 * a * b) * math.cos(math.radians(theta)))
 
   
res1 = law_of_cosines(3.0, 4.0, 90)
print(res1)  # should output: 5.0
```

`math.degrees(rad)` -> deg

`math.radians(deg)` -> rad

Comment: i did not get the error but the output is still not 5

Comment: @NeilNair check it again, I edited it.